# Bash Script; Replacing certain string in filename with another string using find and sed

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that replaces certain string in filename with another string using find command and sed command.

I want to take two arguments; first being variable OLD, the string I'm looking for in filename (string may also contain spaces), second being variable NEW, the string I want to change it to.

I want to find all files that contains OLD in filename AND ends with .jpg or .png in current directories and all subdirectories and change the OLD part with NEW.

```
#! /bin/bash

OLD="${1}"
NEW="${2}"

# maybe..?
for file in `find . -name "*$OLD*\.(jpg|png)"`; do
   # ...
done

# or this..?
find . -name "*$OLD*\.(jpg|png)" | sed -E "s/$OLD/$NEW/"
# ...
```

I have wrote some things but they probably don't make any sense and I'm really confused with bash scripting as I am still very new to it. I will really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just do this, as long as you don't have any special characters in `$OLD` and `$NEW`:

```
for file in $(find -E . -regex ".*$OLD.*\.(jpg|png)$")
do
  echo ${file/$OLD/$NEW}
done
```

EDIT: Seems `find -E` is an extension.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*$OLD.*\.(jpg|png)$"
```

Comment: Does this rename the filename? Isn't echo command only used to print out string?

Comment: Did you want to rename the file? `mv $file ${file/$OLD/$NEW}` instead of `echo`. Even better, unless you really need to script it, there are utilities for multirename; I use the [Renamer plugin for Vim](https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-renamer) which is simply awesome, and lets you interactively rename everything in a directory in seconds.

Comment: Yeah, or even on command line: `vim +Renamer +"%s/$OLD/$NEW" +Ren +q`

Comment: By the way, why do you need that $ at the end of ".*\.(jpg/png)$"?

Comment: It's regular expression for "the end"; otherwise, you'd find `foo.jpg.bak`.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Just one more question, why is the line you added different from the first one? The first one says `".*$OLD.*\.(jpg|png)$"` and the second says `".*\.(jpg|png)$"`.

Comment: Mistake in copying. The main issue is `-E` on my Mac vs `-regextype posix-extended` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!